# Displaying Png Image in J2me

Tags: java, java-me, midp, lcdui

I am having  problem of displaying PNG image where as JPG image is Displaying Perfectly well.

Here is the code of getting Image .

```
Image tImage=Image.createImage("/tasbeeh.jpg");
```

and then draw Image but for png

```
Image tImage=Image.createImage("/tasbeeh.png");
```

throws exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException:
at start.SplashScreen.paint(+56)
at javax.microedition.lcdui.Canvas.callPaint(+85)
at javax.microedition.lcdui.Display.repaint(+82)
```

and

```
java.io.IOException
at javax.microedition.lcdui.ImmutableImage.getImageFromStream(+15)
at javax.microedition.lcdui.ImmutableImage.<init>(+20)
at javax.microedition.lcdui.Image.createImage(+8)
```

Comment: It is giving me Null pointer Exception

Comment: What J2ME profile are you using, and what supplier?

Comment: ava.lang.NullPointerException: 
 at start.SplashScreen.paint(+56)
 at javax.microedition.lcdui.Canvas.callPaint(+85)
 at javax.microedition.lcdui.Display.repaint(+82)

Comment: java.io.IOException
 at javax.microedition.lcdui.ImmutableImage.getImageFromStream(+15)
 at javax.microedition.lcdui.ImmutableImage.<init>(+20)
 at javax.microedition.lcdui.Image.createImage(+8)

Comment: your both images in res forlder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Image.createImage](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Image.html#createImage%28java.lang.String%29) JavaDoc, for that method to throw an exception it must be because the source string is null. This does not seem to be the case. It might be an issue with your `MIDP` or `CLDC` version.

You can try and use other implementations of the `Image.createImage` such as [this](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Image.html#createImage%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) one.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the exception your getting is an IllegalArgumentException,

An IllegalArgumentException is thrown if the first argument is incorrectly formatted or otherwise cannot be decoded.

So your most likely receiving the error due to unsupported format of the image, or truncated data.

**Update**

http://www.ai.univ-paris8.fr/~djedi/j2me-xml/midp20-src/javax/microedition/lcdui/ImmutableImage.html#getImageFromStream(java.io.InputStream)

**getImageFromStream
Throws:
IOException - if there is an error with the stream**

So the stream of data coming in from that png is not formatted as expected, like I say unsupported format of the image, or truncated data.

You should try using a graphics program like paint.net or photoshop and saving as a PNG with different bit formats.

I hope this helps.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
at start.SplashScreen.paint(+56)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            java.io.IOException
 at javax.microedition.lcdui.ImmutableImage.getImageFromStream(+15)
 at javax.microedition.lcdui.ImmutableImage.<init>(+20)